# Обновить запись по условию

Tags: многопоточность, postgresql

Для простоты допустим, что есть таблица, которая хранит только некие максимальные значения:

```
id | name      | max_value
--------------------------
1  | Сущность1 | 10
```

Как обновить запись атомарным запросом только в том случае, если новое `max_value` в запросе больше сохраненного?

Необходимость проверки и записи одним действием обусловлено тем, что база будет писаться несколькими потоками, и если вынести проверку `max_value`, то в результате "гонки" двух потоков со значениями, скажем 20 и 30, в базе может оказаться не максимальное значение.

Comment: одна и та же запись будет изменяться несколькими потоками?

Comment: Все верно. Теоретически, в какой-то момент 2 или более потока могут захотеть обновить одну и ту-же запись. Тут имеются ввиду потоки приложения, которое работает с этой БД

Comment: для этого и существуют блокировки. если запись в данный момент обновляется, то второй запрос не сможет ее обновить и будет ждать

Comment: Да, но для того чтоб запись обновить, надо понимать, нужно ли ее обновлять вообще (см. условие в вопросе). Для этого ее надо прочитать и сравнить `max_value`. Если два потока в режиме гонки прочитают значение 10, решат что их значение больше, и захотят писать своё, то блокировка случится только тут. И тогда поток со значением 30 может оказаться чуточку быстрее. Сразу же после него свое значение запишет поток, у которого оно равно 20. Итог: База сломана, так как содержит неверные данные.

Comment: Мне нужно что-то такое, что сможет заблокировать запись в том числе на чтение для других потоков, пока делает все свои операции. Но я очень плохо разбираюсь в sql, поэтому попросил помощи

Comment: хотите что-то такое - используйте уровень Serializable - https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.5/transaction-iso.html. но скорость транзакций скорее всего упадет.

Comment: Поправьте если ошибаюсь, но это не решает мою проблему. Допустим первый поток создает транзакцию на чтение данных, затем создает на запись. Как раз между этими событиями второй поток создает транзакцию на чтение данных. Получается такая цепочка последовательных транзакций: `1 поток читает -> 2 поток читает -> 1 поток пишет -> 2 поток пишет`. Разница только в том, что теперь первые 2 шага выполняются последовательно, а не параллельно, но база все равно сломана.

Comment: Ну если ситуация действительно такая простая, как написано в тексте вопроса, то вам вообще не надо ничего читать `update table set max_value=X where id=1 and max_value < X` атомарно обновит таблицу именно так, как вы хотите. max_value никогда не уменьшиться. А если все таки ситуация сложнее, чем описано, то читайте данные с помощью `select for update`

Comment: Ситуация действительно такая простая. Нахожу Вашу подсказку изящной. Может оформите простенький ответ?